# Install MSMQ via a Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, msmq

Is there a way to install MSMQ via Group policy in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Perhaps running `ocsetup MSMQ-Container;MSMQ-Server` as a startup script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a startup script:

> dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MSMQ-Container /Norestart /Quiet
>   dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:MSMQ-Server /Norestart /Quiet

Comment: This works, but only need the second line -- first line says something along the lines of MSMQ-Container not being an option even though it comes out of the dism list.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have taken a look at MS TechNet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749102(WS.10).aspx.  Creating a new GPO applying to your OUs and including
a logon script will get this done.

"Create a FirstLogonCommand that runs ServerManagerCmd.exe
For Windows Server 2008, you can create a FirstLogonCommand that runs ServerManagerCmd.exe in your answer file that specifies the proper parameters for configuring MSMQ."

Let me know if you have any questions.  of course recommended to apply to a new test gpo and test ou with 1 user/machine first.